# Which is more preferable? Why? in list type annotation of Dart

Tags: dart

Which should I use in Dart? And why?

I understand that when [omit_local_variable_types](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html) is used, it will naturally be the second use. If there is any other reason, please let me know.

```dart
List<int> numbers = [1,2,3];
```

```dart
var numbers = <int>[1,2,3];
```

Comment: The latter is objectively shorter, especially if you want your variable to be declared with `final` or `const`.  The first form also runs the risk of accidentally omitting the element type; `List numbers = [1, 2, 3];` declares `numbers` to be a `List<dynamic>`, whereas it would still be a `List<int>` for `var numbers = [1, 2, 3];`.

Answer (score 0):

Both declarations do the same thing here; it's simply a matter of preference.

It's worth noting that the Effective Dart guidelines [recommend](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-redundantly-type-annotate-initialized-local-variables) the use of the `omit_local_variable_types` lint.

Additionally, the following also works:

```dart
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
```

Technically, the type of the list object is determined by the type specified on the right hand side if one is given (preventing type inference from the variable type being used). The following code would fail at runtime, because the created list is a `List<int>`.

```dart
List<num> numbers = <int>[1, 2, 3];
numbers[4] = 4.0;
```